# Azure blockchain mining nodes not running

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-virtual-machine, azure-blockchain-service

I created a blockchain using azure's blockchain as a service. 
I encountered the following problem :

In the admin site, I see that my mining node are not running :

[image: mining nodes not running]

And I can sent ether from an account to another for example.

However, I am sure that I started my VMs and it is confirmed when see my dashboard :

[image: Mining VMs running]

Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, except modify `adminSitePort`, `gethRPCPort`, you also need modify `  "destinationPortRange": "3000",` "destinationPortRange": "8545", in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that blockchain could not ssh to your VM. You need check your NSG and Azure Load Balancer Inbound NAR rules. Please the port is you needed.
[image]

You could use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network) to deploy your blockchain service. Click `Deploy to Azure`. You could modify the value in Portal.
[image]

According to your scenario, you need modify 5 values.

```
"adminSitePort": 3000,
"sshNATFrontEndStartingPort": 3000,
"destinationPortRange": "3000",
"gethRPCPort": 8545,
"destinationPortRange": "8545",
```